# Class name does not name a type - Pulling my hair out

Tags: c++

I've been working on this for several hours and I can't figure out which class is giving me problems.  I get a bunch of 'VendSlot' does not name a type" errors.  I appreciate any help you can provide.  I am new to C++ and extremely frustrated.

```
//class Snack
#ifndef SNACK_HPP
#define SNACK_HPP
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Snack
{
private:
    string name;
    double price;
    int calories;

public:
    Snack();
    Snack(string name, double price, int calories);
    string getName();
    double getPrice();
    int getNumCalories();
};


#endif
```

Snack.cpp

```
#include "Snack.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Snack::Snack()
{
    name = "bottled water";
    price = 1.75;
    calories = 0;
}

Snack::Snack(string n, double p, int c)
{
    name = n;
    price = p;
    calories = c;
}

string Snack::getName()
{
    return name;
}

double Snack::getPrice()
{
    return price;
}

int Snack::getNumCalories()
{
    return calories;
}
```

VendSlot.hpp

```
#ifndef VENDSLOT_HPP
#define VENDSLOT_HPP
#include "Snack.hpp"

class VendSlot
{
private:
    Snack s;
    int amount;

public:
    VendSlot();
    VendSlot(Snack s, int a);
    Snack getSnack();
    int getAmount();
    int decrementAmount();
};
#endif
```

VendSlot.cpp

```
#include "VendSlot.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

VendSlot();

VendSlot::VendSlot()
{
    Snack s1;
    s = s1;
    amount = 5;
}

VendSlot::VendSlot(Snack s1, int a)
{
    s = s1;
    amount = 5;
}

Snack VendSlot::getSnack()
{
    Snack s1;
    s = s1;
    return s;
}

int VendSlot::getAmount()
{
    return amount;
}

int VendSlot::decrementAmount()
{
    amount--;
    return amount;
}
```

MiniVend.hpp

```
#ifndef MINIVEND_HPP
#define MINIVEND_HPP
#include "VendSlot.hpp"

class MiniVend
{
private:
    VendSlot vs1;
    VendSlot vs2;
    VendSlot vs3;
    VendSlot vs4;
    double money;

public:
    MiniVend();
    MiniVend(VendSlot v1, VendSlot v2, VendSlot v3, VendSlot v4, double money);
    int numEmptySlots();
    double getMoney();
    double valueOfSnacks();
    void buySnack();
};
#endif
```

MiniVend.cpp

```
#include "VendSlot.hpp"

using namespace std;

MiniVend::MiniVend(VendSlot v1, VendSlot v2, VendSlot v3, VendSlot v4, double m)
{
    vs1 = v1;
    vs2 = v2;
    vs3 = v3;
    vs4 = v4;
    money = m;
}

double MiniVend::getMoney()
{
    return money;
}

int MiniVend::numEmptySlots()
{
    int numSlots = 0;
    if (vs0.getAmount() == 0)
        slots++;
    if (vs1.getAmount() == 0)
        slots++;
    if (vs2.getAmount() == 0)
        slots++;
    if (vs3.getAmount() == 0)
        numSlots++;

    return numSlots;
}

double MiniVend::valueOfSnacks()
{
    double value = 0;
    value = (vs0.getSnack().getPrice() * vs0.getAmount() +
    (vs1.getSnack().getPrice() * vs1.getAmount()) +
    (vs2.getSnack().getPrice() * vs2.getAmount()) +
    (vs3.getSnack().getPrice() * vs3.getAmount()))

    return value;
}

void MiniVend::buySnack(int slot);
{
    if (slot == 0 && vs0.getAmount >= 1)
    {
        money = money + vs0.getSnack.getPrice();
        vs0.decrementAmount();
    }

    else if (slot == 1 && vs1.getAmount >= 1)
    {
        money = money + vs1.getSnack.getPrice();
        vs1.decrementAmount();
    }

    else if (slot == 2 && vs2.getAmount >= 1)
    {
        money = money + vs2.getSnack.getPrice();
        vs2.decrementAmount();
    }

    else if (slot == 3 && vs3.getAmount >= 1)
    {
        money = money + vs3.getSnack.getPrice();
        vs3.decrementAmount();#include "Snack.hpp"
    }

    else
        cout << "Sold out.  Please select another Snack." << endl;
}
```

Main

```
#include "MiniVend.hpp"
#include "Snack.hpp"
#include "VendSlot.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

 int main()
{
 Snack s2("candy bar", 1.25, 300);
 Snack s3("root beer", 2.00, 450);

 VendSlot groucho(s1, 2);
 VendSlot harpo(s2, 1);
 VendSlot chico(s3, 0);
 VendSlot zeppo;  // five bottles of water

 MiniVend machine(groucho, harpo, chico, zeppo, 0);

 cout << machine.numEmptySlots() << endl;
 cout << machine.valueOfSnacks() << endl;
 cout << machine.getMoney() << endl;
 machine.buySnack(1);
 cout << machine.numEmptySlots() << endl;
 cout << machine.valueOfSnacks() << endl;
 cout << machine.getMoney() << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `MiniVend.cpp` isn't including `MiniVend.hpp`.

Comment: `VendSlot();` - what is the purpose of this line, near the beginning of `VendSlot.cpp`?

Comment: Include the error message in the question and not the unnecessary stuff. The error message will mostly tell you at which line you have the problem. Only include the related stuff in the question.

Answer (score 0):

- At `MiniVend.hpp` your buySnack does not take any parameters `void buySnack();`, but at Minivend.cpp you are defining an argument at your        function header 
  `void MiniVend::buySnack(int slot);`, and you shouldn't be using an semicolon too.
- Your MiniVend.cpp file should also include the `"MiniVend.hpp"` header as well.
- At MiniVend.cpp in the declaration of function `int MiniVend::numEmptySlots()` `vs0` is not defined anywhere in the code as well as `slots`
- At you main function you are trying to declare this `VendSlot groucho(s1, 2);`, but you have not defined `s1` anywhere in your main function

That's what I have found so far. Hope this helps and please use comments when posting a question so that everyone can understand the purpose of the code.